# changing the color of individual points on an excel graph using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, pattern-matching

I have a graph where I am measuring a process. And based on certain criteria:

Criteria 1: A run of 8 points below the mean (only has to be consistently below the mean, can be up or down.

Criteria 2: trying to identify cyclical data so I want to detect when in a stream of three data points (8, 10, 7) the highest number (with two lower numbers either side) and vice versa).

Then if these patterns are detected in the data, I want to use VBA to change the color of these specific data points that meet the criteria.

Is this possible? Not sure how to implement it? Essentially I would pass the function a series of data, column A would have dates and column B would have values between 1-10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below sub changes the colour of the individual points where the value is greater than 50. You could modify this code where I have `If vals(x) > 50 Then` to have an if statement that will do your pattern matching

**EDIT** I've modified the so that it only colours those values > 50 where the previous values where also >50

```
Sub ColourOver50()

     Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
     Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

     vals = s.Values

     For x = WorksheetFunction.Max(LBound(vals), 8) To UBound(vals)
     Dim flag As Boolean
     flag = True
     For i = 0 To 7
          If vals(x - i) > 50 Then
               'do nothing
          Else
               flag = False
          End If
     Next

     If flag = True Then
        With s.Points(x)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
     End If

     Next x

 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tyler! Wondering do you know how to do this same thing using python. - graph the data, and highlight 1. a run of 8 above or below the mean, and 2. cyclical data (where there is a sequence of high low high, or low high, low?)

Comment: Typer! rather than hightlighting just any point which is above > 50 is it possible to modify your code to have all points blue except for any instances where the are for example 8 points in a row which are all above 50, and color those red? I'm looking to be able to do this in both VBA and python! Thanks

Comment: @yoshiserry dont change the question after you get an answer. Im not strong at Python so cant help you there unfortunately. I suggest you open a new question to get the python answers you need. In the mean time I've updated the code to highlight values >50 where it has been >50 for 8 previous values. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @TylerDurden, i'll do that, post another question, how did you manage to get the graph to flash different colours, did you make it in flash or something?

Comment: no i just looped my code with `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue( 0:00:1 ))` in for loop that ran to 100 and made the color change. Then  i created a gif. The graph doesnt flash in my spreadsheet unless i run the macro